# how to schedule a perl program in windows

Tags: windows, perl, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a perl program using windows scheduler. The program would connect to Microsoft Access 2007 and execute a macro in it. If I execute the perl program it works fine but in scheduler the execution never completes and the status of the scheduler will always remain "running  the program" and desired output is not generated. I tried giving absolute path names where ever required but still the issue remains the same. Can anyone help me figure out how to resolve this problem.

Comment: In task scheduler your choose what user will runs the task. The user has enough permissions? Could you print a log in the program to look in what step of your script is the problem ?

Comment: @user3452713 i used `-update > c:\my_log.txt 2>&1` and the file is empty(no data)

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [`Schedule a Task`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) open the Task Scheduler and create a basic task.

I created one to run the following script `perl C:/devel/hello.pl` 5 minutes from now:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Time::Piece;

my $file = 'C:/devel/hello.log';

open my $fh, '>>', $file;

print $fh scalar(localtime), "\n";
```

If this works properly, that you can assume it is likely something to do with permissions and being able to access your Access database.  Either way, confirm that you can get a basic script scheduled and working before trying for a more complicated one.

Comment: tried scheduling the above program, I could not execute it using the scheduler. so I created a batch file which would execute the perl program and it worked. tried the same way on access DB but the execution terminates half the way.